# Adding an array to different keys in NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm adding an array to a NSDictionary with different keys.
Here's the abstraction:

```
NSMutableDictionary *myDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];   
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        [myArray removeAllObjects];      
        [myArray addObject:i];
        [myArray addObject:i];   
        [myArray addObject:i];   
        [myDict setObject:myArray forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@“%i”, i]];
         NSLog(@"%@", myDict);
    }
```

and that's what i get on output:

i = 1

“1” =     (
        “1”,
        “1”,
        “1”,
        “1”
    );

i = 2

“1” =     (
        “2”,
        “2”,
        “2”,
        “2”
    );

“2” =     (
        “2”,
        “2”,
        “2”,
        “2”
    );

i = 3

“1” =     (
        “3”,
        “3”,
        “3”,
        “3”
    );

“2” =     (
        “3”,
        “3”,
        “3”,
        “3”
    );

“3” =     (
        “3”,
        “3”,
        “3”,
        “3”
    );

but how to get this?:

i = 3

“1” =     (
        “1”,
        “1”,
        “1”,
        “1”
    );

“2” =     (
        “2”,
        “2”,
        “2”,
        “2”
    );

“3” =     (
        “3”,
        “3”,
        “3”,
        “3”
    );

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: Are you sure that's the code you are running?

Answer (score 0):

You can't reuse the same array over and over. Do this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *myDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];   
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    [myArray addObject:@(i)];
    [myArray addObject:@(i)];   
    [myArray addObject:@(i)];   
    [myDict setObject:myArray forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i]];
     NSLog(@"%@", myDict);
}
```

Please note that you can't add `int` values directly to an array. Note that you need to wrap them as `NSNumber` objects.

Comment: Does this even compile? Adding an int to an NSMutableArray?

Comment: @huhitschris Good point. I just copied that code from the OP's original code. I've updated the code so it will work.

Comment: I can't seem to make this edit myself so maybe you can make it: The `stringWithFormat:` argument has smart-quotes, please replace.

Comment: Well, you can of course reuse the same array again and again. It will lead to strange and unexpected and undesirable effects, but you can reuse it.

Comment: @gnasher729 You can't reuse the same array over and over to solve this particular problem. Of course an array can be added over and over in general.

Comment: it's just an abstraction. no matter what i'm adding to *myArray.
the point is to get the right NSDictionary. Rmaddy, thanks for the solution.

Comment: @aa.ss Glad I could help. As a new user I'll point out that you should upvote helpful answers and accept the best answer that solved your issue. This tells people that your question has been solved.

Answer (score -1):

```
NSMutableDictionary *myDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:3];
    [myArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i]];
    [myArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i]];
    [myArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i]];
    [myDict setObject:myArray forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i]];
    NSLog(@"%@", myDict);
}
```

Comment: You should not post code-only answers. Please add some explanation of what was wrong and what changes were needed.

Comment: Thanks. I was just trying to do what he asked "but how to get this?:" I showed how to get this.

Comment: The difference is that you were using the same array object and just removing its contents and building it again and then putting it into the dict again. In your code you were just putting the same array object in the dictionary 3 times, and so any reference to that array object will show you what it currently has in it, not what was in it when you originally put it in the dictionary. You have to create a new array object each iteration of the loop so you get 3 different array objects in your dictionary. Any up votes or acceptance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: understood. thanks mikomi for explanation. unf, i don't have enough reputation for voting. but your help is priceless for me!

Comment: So I'm down voted for giving the exact working code, and then giving a paragraph explanation and the OP being very satisfied. Great community.